# BeautifulSoup4: change text inside xml tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I simply want to change the text inside an xml tag after it becomes a BeautifulSoup object.

Current code:

```
example_string = '<conversion><person>John</person></conversion>'
bsoup = BeautifulSoup(example_string)
bsoup.person.text = 'Michael'
```

running this code in my console renders this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How can I change the value inside the `person` xml tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`.string` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), not `.text` which is read-only:

```
example_string = '<conversion><person>John</person></conversion>'
bsoup = BeautifulSoup(example_string, "xml")
bsoup.person.string = 'Michael'
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: example_string = '<conversion><person>John</person></conversion>'
    ...: bsoup = BeautifulSoup(example_string, "xml")
    ...: bsoup.person.string = 'Michael'
    ...: 
    ...: print(bsoup.prettify())
    ...: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conversion>
 <person>
  Michael
 </person>
</conversion>
```